# Unable to run job in any queue in Sun Grid Engine

Tags: sungridengine

I am running Sun Grid Engine and just finished installing it. I submit a job using a shell wrapper script from command line like

> ./hello_world_qsub.sh

but when I run it I get the following error

> Unable to run job: b410 your job is not allowed to run in any queue . Your job 1("hello_world.sh") has been submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer myself,

In the user configuration tab in qmon, add the name of your executing host and click modify that did the job

Comment: Hi Sabhiri, could you detail what has been added using qmon?